# Method to reverse string only if it has less than four letters

Tags: ruby

I need to write a ruby method that reverses a string only if it has less than four characters.

```
# Write a method that reverses
# a string ONLY if it's shorter than
# 4 letters.
# Otherwise, the string is
# returned as-is.
# (Hint: strings have
# a built-in .length method!)
# conditional_reverse("yo")
# => "oy"
# conditional_reverse("hello")
# => "hello"
```

Here is the code I came up with.

```
def conditional_reverse(string)
  good = string.length
  if good < 4
    puts string.reverse
  else
    puts string
  end
  puts conditional_reverse("cat")
end
```

When I run it in repl I get the following response

```
:conditional_reverse
```

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: take puts conditional_reverse("cat") out of the function.

Comment: How are you running it in repl?  What does the line you type look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put `puts conditional_reverse("cat")` out side our `def`

```
def conditional_reverse(string)
  good = string.length 
  if good < 4 
    puts string.reverse
  else 
    puts string
  end 
end

conditional_reverse("cat")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You are callind your method in its definition. Avoid it if you are not writing a recursive method.

```
def conditional_reverse(s)
  s.length < 4 ? s.reverse : s
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @Ursus is perfect, but in case you want to go with your way the change you have to do is this;

```
def conditional_reverse(string)
good = string.length 
if good < 4 
    puts string.reverse
else 
    puts string
    end 
end
puts conditional_reverse("cat")
```

Answer (score 0):

What the others said, plus...

You get that response from irb because in recent versions of Ruby, a method definition returns the method name as a symbol.

Also, your problem specifies that the string should be reversed, not that the string should be *output* reversed; so you should remove the `puts` calls and just manipulate the string.

For the benefit of your readers, I recommend being specific with your names.  `good = string.length` could be changed to `needs_reversing = string.length < 4`, for example.